# Doing forensics using PowerShell in Windows, linking ports to applications

Tags: windows, security, powershell, ports

In order to correctly do forensics; in finding vulnerabilities, that the security team has revealed in their security scans.

The two commands I use mostly do this job is:

```
c:\ netstat -abno | find "port number"
```

This command gives me a process id for the port that has the vulnerability.

After this;

I use the following comand to associate the application running on that process associated with the port above.

```
c:\ wmic process | find "Proccess Id" > proc.txt
```

Which gives me the application linked to that process, from here, I just research the application to find the vulnerability embedded within.

My question to all your PowerShell experts is;

How do I acomplish the same process in PowerShell?

Now keep in mind, I start with a port and end up with an application which is associated to that port with the steps listed above.

My thoughts:

It probably has something to do with:
`Get-Process`
and
`Get-NetTCPConnection`

But can't fully understand how to break down the thought process as explained above.

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2011/02/10/how-to-find-running-processes-and-their-port-number/ should help.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell you can use, as you mentioned, a combination of `Get-NetTCPConnection` and `Get-Process` like so:

```
$port = 80
Get-Process -PID @(Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort $port| select -ExpandProperty OwningProcess -Unique)
```

Comment: Can you add "-FileVersionINfo" in this little script to spit out the version of the file for this process? thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, I always do it with (as admin)

`netstat -abno | findstr portnum`

`tasklist | findstr PID`

or if you are only worried about listeners:

`netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr portnum`

`tasklist | findstr PID`

Comment: Nice! Will Get-Process / Get NetTCPConnection give us any additional useful daeta, for example, the location of the application? etc?